# How do I access children of a styled-component?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm in a React role after several years away from it.  I seem to have forgotten how to do some things.  I'm working on a large, convoluted codebase.  I'm working with a styled component like this:

```
export const MyContent = styled.div`
    border-left-color: #d2e1a1;
    border-bottom-color: #d2e1a1;
`
```

In the file that imports that component:

```
export const MyContentGroup = () => {
    ...
    return (
        <MyContent
            id=`my-content-id-${contentHeader}`
            onKeyDown={(e) => {
                if(e.key == 'Tab' && e.currentTarget.id.match(/^my-content-id/) {
                  // I want to manually set focus to the first child
                }
            }}
        />
    )
}
```

Like it says in the comment, I want to manually alter the tab order so that when tabbing through the page, focus gets set to the first child of MyContent, something like `children[0].focus()`.  How can I access MyContent's children?  I thought it was built-in, and automatically available to all components.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a state variable that stores the focus state of the child component inside the parent and then pass that variable as a prop to the child. That way, whenever the tab keypress event happens, the focus state gets updated and the parent component re-renders the child with the updated prop.

Your code might look something like this:

```
export const MyContentGroup = () => {
    ...
    const [focused, setFocused]=useState(false)
    
    return (
        <MyContent
            focused={focused}
            id=`my-content-id-${contentHeader}`
            onKeyDown={(e) => {
                if(e.key == 'Tab' && e.currentTarget.id.match(/^my-content-id/)) {
                    setFocused(true)
                }
            }}
        />
    )
}
```

Then, if you have multiple children, instead of storing the focus state of one child, you store a reference to the child component currently focused or `null` if there are none.